# NTLM authentication with EE

Tags: add-on-development, email

My project needs NTLM authentication. This is not core function as i found here: [Can ExpressionEngine….?](http://ee-spotlight.com/reviews/can_expressionengine)

Are there any existing add-ons which provide this? If not, where would be an appropriate place to find a developer for this?

Thanks!

Comment: We don't allow job posts on Stack Exchange (see the [FAQ](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq)). I have reworded your question to remove references to this.

Answer (score 1):

There are no existing add-ons for NTLM authentication out in the wild.

If you're looking for an EE add-on, do a search on [devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com). If you don't find anything there, I'd suggest looking for a developer to write one for you - try [director-ee](http://director-ee.com). (It is certainly possible using [these extension hooks](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/member_auth/index.html)).

Comment: Thank you. I checked devot:ee before. Thought maybe if somebody has something in the pipeline. Will check now director-ee.

Comment: You probably already know, but if not, Microsoft no longer recommends using NTLM authentication in applications, since it doesn't support the latest security and encryption. I believe that happen in 2010. So I can't imagine too many people would support an outdated protocol.